# @twilio/video-room-monitor with react 18

Tags: react-18, twilio-javascript

When I do:

npm install @twilio/video-processors

I get the following error;

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @twilio/video-room-monitor@1.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.14.14
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.14.14
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         2 more (@mui/x-date-pickers, the root project)
npm ERR!       4 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.14.14
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.14.14
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.14.9" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@mui/x-date-pickers, the root project)
npm ERR!     4 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.14.14
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.14.14
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.14.9" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@mui/x-date-pickers, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.14.14
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine
npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.14.13" from @mui/system@5.14.14
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.14.14" from @mui/material@5.14.14
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         1 more (@mui/x-date-pickers)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers, the root project)
npm ERR!   41 more (@emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @twilio/video-room-monitor@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@twilio/video-room-monitor
npm ERR!   @twilio/video-room-monitor@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @twilio/video-room-monitor@1.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@twilio/video-room-monitor
npm ERR!     @twilio/video-room-monitor@"^1.0.1" from the root project
```

Is there a version of @twilio/video-room-monitor that is compatible with react 18? Will the --force option potentially cause any problems?